# Books on designing clinical trials for psychotherapy research

Tags: references, clinical-trials, psychology

I'm designing a clinical trial that will evaluate a behavioral therapy against a control condition, and I'm looking for some good texts on this topic. There are a lot of books on clinical trials in medicine, but I've had a hard time finding one that also covers the topics specific to psychotherapy research.

For instance, topics like choosing an appropriate control group and evaluating the therapist's adherence and competence are different in psychotherapy research than in drug trials. Any tips on a comprehensive book on this topic would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think that much of the methodology of general books on clinical trial design would apply to psychotherapy research.  But in hunting on the internet I did find this one book on methodology for medical research in clinical psychology.

[Research Design in Clinical Psychology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0205332927)

Comment: Issues of the overall design is covered in general books on clinical trails. But I'm hoping to find a book that covers the aspects that's specific to clinical psychology. "Research Design in Clinical Psychology" seems to be a bit introductory, but I will take a closer look at it.

Comment: I was just taking a shot in the dark.

Comment: I appreciate it!